# gallery image not showing their order

Tags: javascript, php, css

[image]I have an gallery.php file.It consist Albums and it's gallery images. My problem is when I click on Album image, Gallery images start to showing from images 4/4 then 3/4 and so on.

gallery.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-port">
            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="menu-grid-main">
                    <?php 
                    include("database/connection.php");
                    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * from Album_image where status='process'");
                    while ($row1= mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                    ?>

                    <div class="col-md-4 menu-grid wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                        <?php 
                        include("database/connection.php");
                        $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * from Gallery_image where aid=$row1[aid]");
                        while ($row2= mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { 
                        ?>
                        <a href="admin/gcatch//<?php echo $row2['image'] ?>" data-lightbox="<?php echo $row1['name']?>" >
                        <?php }?>
                        <img src="admin/acatch/<?php echo $row1['image'] ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                        <h3><?php echo $row1['name']?></h3>                 
                        <p><?php echo $row1['des']?></p>
                    </div>

                    <?php }?>           
                 <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>
```

I used lightbox effect to showing gallery images

Please anyone help me to showing image proper format

Comment: with out an `order by` in your select query, you never know what order the data will be in

Comment: I tried that also no changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is syntax issue. try this

```
<div class="menu-port">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu-grid-main">
            <?php 
                    include("database/connection.php");
                    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * from Album_image where status='process'");
                    while ($row1= mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                    ?>
            <?php 
                        include("database/connection.php");
                        $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * from Gallery_image where aid=$row1[aid]");
                        while ($row2= mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { 
                        ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 menu-grid wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s">

                <a href="admin/gcatch//<?php echo $row2['image'] ?>" data-lightbox="<?php echo $row1['name']?>" >

                    <img src="admin/acatch/<?php echo $row1['image'] ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
                <h3><?php echo $row1['name']?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $row1['des']?></p>
            </div>
            <?php }?>
            <?php }?>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir..it's working, but the same album images repeated in row2 Times. How can I resolve this.. @Mahesh

Comment: Yes that because of your looping it. can you get result from one query instead of 2. You should join the table  and get 1 query result. Then you can loop one query result.

Answer (score 1):

this query is better for fetch data

```
"SELECT * from Gallery_image where aid=$row1[aid] ORDER BY id DESC"
```

ordering result is best way to figure out what data in what order is fetching

**REMEMBER : mysql_* functions (mysql_connect OR mysql_query) are deprecated ! you should use PDO or at least mysqli functions**

here is some resource to learn PDO : [PDO and mysqli](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)
/ [intro to PDO (laracast tutorial)](https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners/episodes/13)